# No such file or directory: pr2_moveit_config/temp/pr2.urdf

Tags: moveit, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started seeing:

```
$ roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 268, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 257, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 206, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 121, in _load_config
    self.config = roslaunch.config.load_config_default(self.roslaunch_files, self.port, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 428, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 694, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 666, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 630, in _recurse_load
    val = self._include_tag(tag, context, ros_config, default_machine, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 571, in _include_tag
    default_machine, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 610, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 236, in _param_tag
    value = self.param_value(verbose, name, ptype, *vals)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/loader.py", line 453, in param_value
    with open(textfile, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/groovy/share/pr2_moveit_config/temp/pr2.urdf'
```

No temp dir found in `pr2_moveit_config`:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/share/pr2_moveit_config$ tree -L 1
.
├── cmake
├── config
├── launch
└── package.xml
3 directories, 30 files
```

The file with the same name is found in different pkg:

```
$ find . -iname 'pr2.urdf'
./stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_mechanism_model/pr2.urdf
```

What is wrong? Thanks!

`ros-groovy-pr2-moveit-config 0.3.10-0quantal-20130416-1824-+0000`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60938/no-such-file-or-directory:-pr2_moveit_config/temp/pr2.urdf/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Isaac,

You are using shadow fixed probably for your debs, and in version 0.3.10 there is a folder that should be installed, but it is not. Version 0.3.11 fixed that (building now)

Ioan

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-18**:
0.3.11 works as it used to. Thanks!